# Mostrar array por JOptionPane y recoger resultado

Tags: java, array, ventana

tengo un problemilla. Quiero mostrar un array en un JOptionPane, lo hago asi.

```
String[] continentes = { "ANorte", "ASur", "Africa", "Europa", "Asia", "Oceania" };
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(continentes));
```

Asi, muestro el array por el JOptionPane, pero el problema, es cuando quiero que me ingrese uno de esos valores, u otro, ya me encargare yo de hacer una excepcion.

Pare recoger un dato de un JOptionPane, suelo hacer esto:

```
String aux= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce algo");
```

Y ahora, aux, tiene un string con lo que ha introducido, pero si pongo:

```
String aux = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(continentes));
```

Me da este error,

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String[]

y no se como solucionarlo. Quiero que me aparezca un cuadrado para introducir un nombre y poder recogerlo.

Doy las gracias a todos, seguramente sera un fallo muy simple, pero no he encontrado nada.

Answer (score 5):

`showMessageDialog` no retornara nada (puesto su firma indica que el return type es Void.) recuerda que `showMessageDialog` es **unicamente** para mostrar un mensaje. lo que deseas hacer es un `showInputDialog` con Opciones, por tanto:

Tomando como Referencia el Tutorial de Oracle Con respecto a [Jdialogs link aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

tenemos que: 
showInputDialog es lo que deseamos utilizar. dada tu necesidad tenemos opciones:

> `String[] continentes = { "ANorte", "ASur", "Africa", "Europa", "Asia", "Oceania" };`

```
String[] continentes = {"ANorte", "ASur", "Africa", "Europa", "Asia", "Oceania"};
/*
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog( <Ventana padre>,
   "mensaje a desplegar",
   "titulo de la ventana",
    Tipo de JoptionPane,
    Icono,
    Opciones,
    Opcion default);
*/
Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Elija un Continente",
"Seleccion",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,continentes,null);
//si se cierra la ventan o le da cancel el objecto selection es nulo por tanto verificar eso
if(Objects.isNull(selection)){
    System.out.println("opcion invalida!");
}else{
    System.out.printf("opcion elegida: %s",selection);
    System.out.println();
}
```

y esto se vera asi:

[image: ejemplo de resultado]

Consideraciones importantes: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` retorna un `Object` por tanto se debe verificar que no sea nulo y cuando se utilize sea String (que es muy probable pero no esta garantizado.)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] continentes = { "ANorte", "ASur", "Africa", "Europa", "Asia", "Oceania" };
```

Y si lo hiciera de tipo entero

```
Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Elija un Continente",
"Seleccion",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,continentes,null);
```

No lo puedo mostrar así me marca un error cual seria la solución

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/389064)